# Can photons travel through space independent of time?

Tags: electromagnetism, photons, electrons, relativity

I read an article about advanced photons and they stated that photons traveled back in time to hit an electron. Can photons really travel back in time and if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

> Can photons travel through space independent of time?

That's what they do. They don't travel forward through time in any real sense. It takes a photon 8 minutes to travel through space from the Sun to you. You time such motion on a clock. But take a look at what that clock really does. It isn't literally measuring the flow of time. It's "clocking up" some kind of regular cyclical motion, and showing you a cumulative display called the time. All you're doing is comparing one motion through space against another.

> I read an article about advanced photons and they stated that photons traveled back in time to hit an electron. Can photons really travel back in time and if so, how?

No they can't. They travel through space. They don't travel forward through time at all. So they can't travel back in time. At one point a physicists called Wheeler suggested antiparticles were particles travelling back in time, and you can hear talk of the positron being a time-reversed electron. But like Gennaro said, they're opposite in some respects, that's all. There is no time-travelling going on.

Answer (score 0):

In the Newtonian picture of Mechanics, there is just one clock for the entire universe which synchronises motion everywhere, in the same way there is a single clock in a computer, and by which all processes are timed. The traditional nomenclature for this notion of time is *absolute time*.

This picture, in relativity changes dramatically; instead every particle carries its own clock; this notion of time is called *proper time*.

For photons, this clock is stopped - it doesn't tick; one might as well say, it doesn't have a clock; or that it doesn't have a notion of time.

Traditionally, one says that one cannot move (boost) into a photons rest-frame; and photons of course move at the speed of light bejng massless; which demonstrates that 'no proper time' is not particular to photons - but to any massless particles.

Feynman, following the the work of stuckelberg, developed a pictorial calculus - Feynman diagrams - where  particles can be viewed as moving backwards in time; but they're never observed to do so - that would be a violation of the conventional notions of causality.